# What is the difference between Savoir and Connaître?

Tags: sens

Both verbs mean "to know." Or do they? My online French class isn't giving me a very good description, and neither is Google Translate.

Comment: P.S. Welcome to French Language Stack Exchange! You're invited to take the **[tour](https://french.stackexchange.com/tour)** and visit the **[Help Centre](https://french.stackexchange.com/help)**. It's great that you're bringing French questions here (and please do ask more). We do ask, though, that you first do a search to see if your question has already been answered. If it hasn't, include a quick line in your question like: "I checked here and here, but I'm still not totally clear on it," so we know that we're not just saying things that are available and you haven't found yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Written just before Laure spotted the duplicate! Oh well, perhaps another iteration will be useful.)

An English answer follows the French one.

---

Certes, les deux termes se chevauchent, mais pas entièrement. C'est vrai alors que [les dictionnaires](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/savoir) qui glosent « savoir » par « avoir connaissance de » ne sont pas trop utiles à ce régard.

L'enseignement général qu'on donne (au moins ici au Canada) est ceci :

« Savoir » s'emploie pour des réponses, des faits, des dates — tout ce qui exigerait que tu **consultes** un dictionnaire ou une encyclopédie.

> Quelle est la réponse ? Je ne **sais** pas ...
>   
> <sub>Je ne l'ai pas apprise.</sub>

« Connaître » s'emploie pour des personnes, des lieux, des expériences — tout ce avec quoi tu dois **te familiariser**.

> **Connais**-tu cette femme-là ? C'est la dauphine, la femme du dauphin.
>   
> <sub>On ne s'est pas encore rencontré.</sub>

Ces mots ont tous les deux toute une gamme de significations, dont beaucoup sont figurées, mais l'essentiel est qu'elles naîssent chacune de cette distinction fondamentale : connaissance sémantique vs. connaissance épisodique, expérientielle. Ce trésor m'a été assez pour faire un commencement en tout cas, et pour assimiler peu à peu les autres sens possibles au fur et à mesure dans mes lectures suivantes.

P.S. Un autre sens de « savoir » : lorsqu'il est suivi d'un infinitif, ce mot veut dire « savoir *comment* faire » ou (plutôt archaïque) « pouvoir ».

> Éloignez-vous, voleurs ! J'ai un grand bâton et je sais me défendre !!

---

There certainly is a lot of overlap, but it isn't total. Though it's true that [dictionaries](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/savoir) that gloss "savoir" as *avoir connaissance de* aren't very helpful in this regard.

The general wisdom given (at least here in Canada) is this:

*Savoir* is used for answers, facts, dates — things you could **look up** in a dictionary or encyclopedia.

> Quelle est la réponse ? Je ne **sais** pas ...
>   
> <sub>I don't know the answer. = I have not learned it.</sub>

*Connaître* is used for people, places, experiences — things you must **become familiar with**.

> **Connais**-tu cette femme-là ? C'est la dauphine, la femme du dauphin.
>   
> <sub>Do you know that woman? = Are you acquainted with her?</sub>

Each one has a wide range of meanings, many of them figurative, but the idea is that they all spring from that basic distinction — semantic knowledge vs. episodic, experiential knowledge. That nugget was enough to get me started, anyway, and to gradually absorb the other possible meanings as I encountered them in later reading.

P.S. Another important meaning of *savoir* : when followed by an infinitive, it means "to know how to" or (more archaic) "to be able to".

> Éloignez-vous, voleurs ! J'ai un grand bâton et je sais me défendre !!
>   
> <sub>I know how to defend myself!</sub>