# When to use Savoir and Connaitre ?

Tags: verbes

'Je connais le nom de cette femme' is correct? Since, it is just an information shouldn't it be savoir instead of connaitre?

Comment: See the question: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/39/when-to-use-conna%c3%aetre-and-when-to-use-savoir/13759#13759

Comment: Also https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26294/what-is-the-difference-between-savoir-and-conna%c3%aetre/26296#26296

Answer (score 0):

**Savoir**, with a **noun** or **pronoun** object or **introducing a clause** means know in the sense of being **aware of, having learnt, or having been informed about**.

> Je sais la réponse.
>
> Il savait sa leçon.
>
> Savez-vous son nom ?
>
> Je sais comment le faire.
>
> Savez-vous l'heure du train ?
>
> Elle ne savait pas s'il viendrait.
>
> On sait qu'elle est partie pendant la nuit.

**Connaitre** on the other hand, means **know** in the sense of **being familiar with, having an understanding of**.

> Il connait le droit, l'espagnol.
>
> Je connais cet homme, cette ville, le chemin, le bonheur.

"Savoir" means a deeper knowledge than "connaître".

> Je connais ce nom = I have heard about this name;
>
> Je sais son nom = I know his/her name.

See

[When to use "connaître" and when to use "savoir"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/39/when-to-use-conna%c3%aetre-and-when-to-use-savoir/13759#13759)

[What is the difference between Savoir and Connaître?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26294/what-is-the-difference-between-savoir-and-conna%c3%aetre/26296#26296)